# For our Ng-repeat datatable we need recommendation for pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination

In one of the column we have couple of options such as Edit, View, Delete

We use ng-repeat and display the entire records which comes from the back-end.

We use Datatables for rendering the table and don't use td and tr tags like html.

Initially we don't have the pagination.

Currently we face issues in creating the pagination columns and rendering the table.

Is any good plugin available for this?

Hope most of them would come across the same issue earlier.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables ?

Comment: Not an active project

Answer (score 0):

in AngularJS you can use [dir-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) module for show data in html, its power full directive for management data model in html side. but you can also active [pagination](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging) in datatable and use it.

Comment: Can you help me with an example of huge dataset with server side pagination using the above? The general issue is we don't have much time to analyse and looking for something to quickly win